# Is there a way to make a query respect the order of the inputted parameters?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-orm

*(Please let me know if this is completely absurd, that is probably a reason why I haven't found anything on this.)*

This story has two models `Ranking` and `Artist`, `Ranking` is generically related to `Artist` (object_id, content_type... the whole shebang).

I have a list of objects returned by `Ranking.objects.values_list()` ordered by a certain field (in my case `score`). So obviously, if I want to display a list of artists that were ranked, I'd want them in the same order. I've tried different methods, such as `.filter(pk__in=list)`, `.in_bulk(list)`, etc. Tried coercing the result of `.values_list()` into a tuple too.

They all take my list:

```
>>> objects = Ranking.objects.filter(<stuff>).order_by('score')
>>> objects_list = objects.values_list('object_id', flat=True)
>>> objects_list
[8, 1, 2, 15, 14, 3, 13, 31, 16, 5, 4, 7, 32, 9, 37]
```

And return it like so:

```
>>> Artist.objects.filter(id__in=objects_list).values_list('id', flat=True)
[7, 32, 3, 8, 4, 2, 31, 9, 37, 13, 16, 1, 5, 15, 14]
```

(I'm just giving the IDs in the second case for sanity's sake.)

Right now the only way I can get this to work is to create an empty list and loop through the non-`values_list()` query.

```
for item in objects:
    ranked_items.append(item.content_object)
```

This just produces `n` queries, so I'm wondering if there's a better way. As shown by the tags, I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not caused by Django; your database is returning them in this order since no ordering is specified.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my question has to be if PostgreSQL supports this then.