# Making PostgreSQL respect the order of the inputted parameters?

Tags: python, postgresql

This question has a little history — [Is there a way to make a query respect the order of the inputted parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247892/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-query-respect-the-order-of-the-inputted-parameters)

I'm new to building "specialized" queries, so I assumed that if I supply an `IN` clause as part of a `SELECT` query, it'll return results in the same order. Unfortunately that's not the case.

```
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE id IN (8, 1, 2, 15, 14, 3, 13, 31, 16, 5, 4, 7, 32, 9, 37)
>>> [7, 32, 3, 8, 4, 2, 31, 9, 37, 13, 16, 1, 5, 15, 14]
```

(Didn't include the step where I used Python to loop through the result and append the IDs to a list.)

So the question is, is there a way to make Postgres respect the ordering of the parameters given in an `IN` clause by returning results the *same* order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query results will be returned in non-deterministic order unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

If you really want to do the query in the manner you are requesting, then you could construct such a clause.  Here's an example using part of your data.

```
create table artists (
id integer not null primary key,
name char(1) not null);

insert into artists
values
    (8, 'a'),
    (1, 'b'), 
    (2, 'c'),
    (15, 'd'),
    (14, 'e'),
    (3,  'f'),
    (13, 'g');

select *
from artists
where id in (8, 1, 2, 15, 14, 3, 13)
order by
    id = 8 desc,
    id = 1 desc,
    id = 2 desc,
    id = 15 desc,
    id = 14 desc,
    id = 3 desc,
    id = 13 desc;
```

Based on this and on your other question, I think there is something wrong with your model or the way you are trying to do this. Perhaps you should post a more generic question about how to do what you are trying to do.

If you do have artists and ranking tables, you should be able to do something like this (or the equivalent through your ORM).

```
select
    a.*
from
    artists a,
    rankings r
where
    a.id = r.artist_id
order by
    r.score desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did leave a lot out about how my application works. Long story short, a ranking does not only correspond to an artist, but it can correspond to any number of object types that we give it. That said, I'm using Django's generics to create those relations which makes it a bit harder to do what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Very sad that Postgres cannot preserve the order. This would save me from a lot of troubles, too! I'm in a similar situation and the sort order changes several times per minute, so I'm doing the ordering in my app to prevent totally unnecessary database writes. So order by is not an option,

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you let PostGreSQL return the set in any arbitrary order (especially since it's difficult to do fine-grained SQL-level control from a Django interface), then sort it in the way you wish in *Python* -- `theresultset.sort(key=yourlistofids.index)` should do fine (when `theresultset` is the arbitrary-order list resulting from the database and `yourlistofids` is the list whose order you want to preserve).

Comment: Another situation where I wish I could accept both answers. :) Thank you so much, I'm going to personally take this route, but for the interest of people finding this question off of Google, I'm going to accept cope's answer.

Comment: FWIW, I recommend against this solution. The database is designed to do sorting, whereas the app language is not. It'll be much slower than letting the database sort.

Comment: @Theory, Python is **superb** at sorting (data that fits in memory) -- its `timsort` algorithm is so splendid it's also attracted much attention e.g. in the Java world. It's absurd of you to state that (Python) "is not" "designed to do sorting" when it's so *great* at it.

Answer (score -1):

Another way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM artists 
WHERE id IN (8, 1, 2, 15, 14, 3, 13, 31, 16, 5, 4, 7, 32, 9, 37)
ORDER BY POSITION(id::text in '(8, 1, 2, 15, 14, 3, 13, 31, 16, 5, 4, 7, 32, 9, 37)');
```

Comment: The position function determines the position of one string in another string. This will not function properly because not all of the ids are the same number of digits. Suppose you wanted id 14 to be first. You might end up with id 1 being first. Or id 4.